# Code not showing expected message

Tags: c#, database

This code is supposed to prompt the message: "successfully returned" when `textbookid.Text=not empty string` and prompt the message: "selection error" when `textbookid.Text=empty string`. The problem is that when `textbookid.text=empty string` the code prompts: "successfully returned" instead of prompting "selection error".

```
try
{

  connection.Open();

  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
  command.Connection = connection;

  string cb = "UPDATE book SET [Location] = 'lib' WHERE [Book_Id]='"
            + textbookid.Text
            + "'"
            ;

  command = new OleDbCommand(cb);
  command.Connection = connection;

  command.ExecuteReader();

  MessageBox.Show( "Successfully returned",
     "Book Details",
     MessageBoxButtons.OK,
     MessageBoxIcon.Information
     );

  connection.Close();


  //delete_records();
  //refs();
  //refchk();

}
catch
{
  MessageBox.Show("Selection Error.");
}
```

Comment: Why not just put a conditional statement if(textbookid.Text != string.Empty)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're not returning `"Selection Error"` because it's in the `catch` block. In case you're not aware, `catch` will only execute if the code in `try` returns an error.

In your case, you may want to try something like:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbookID.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selection Error.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully returned", "Book Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
}
```

Note, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will return `true` if the string is ... null or empty. There is also `string.IsNullOrWhitespace`, which will return true if string is null, empty or only spaces, i.e. `" "`.

Answer (score 5):

Because a WHERE condition that results in nothing to update doesn't trigger any exception.

In any case you are coding this wrongly. You need to use the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) around your connection and your command, then you need to use a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid Sql Injection and parsing problems, finally, the correct method to use with an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statement is the [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx). By the way, this method returns the number of rows changed by your command and you could use it to emit your error message in case nothing has been changed by your query...

```
try
{
    using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(.....))
    using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cb, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string cb = @"UPDATE book SET [Location] = 'lib' 
                      WHERE [Book_Id]= ?";

        command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = textbookid.Text;
        int rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(rowsUpdated > 0)
             MessageBox.Show("Successfully returned", ....);
        else
             MessageBox.Show("Selection Error."); 
     }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
```

Of course, I assume that you want to emit the error message for any kind of situations in which the command result in nothing updated and not just in the case where the textbox is empty. This could easily blocked with a single line before this code

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbookid.Text))
   return;
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the one I provided because it actually handles what (I think) he is trying to accomplish. +1!

Answer (score 1):

Only because the `textbookid.text` is empty it still is a valid SQL command. Do separate checking beforehand e.g.:

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbookid.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selection Error.");
    return;
}

try 
//the rest of your code
```